# Linq: Group by ID order by Level then alphabetically troubles

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

So I have a dataview that pulls back some information related to an agency and I would like to group the data by agency, so that name only appears once, then order alphabetically, then by Level. Level would refer to Level 1, Level 2, Level 3. Is it possible to do this in Linq? If so, how? Thanks.

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = 
     from agency in dtAllContacts.AsEnumerable()
     orderby agency.Field<Int32?>("ID") == null ? 0 : agency.Field<Int32>("ID")
     orderby agency.Field<Int32>("Level")  
     select agency;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is not working, because you sort collection two times - first time by id, and than you sort it again, but by level. What you need is sorting by id AND level at same time. So, you need single `orderby` operator:

```
 from agency in dtAllContacts.AsEnumerable()
 orderby agency.Field<Int32?>("ID") == null ? 0 : agency.Field<Int32>("ID"),
         agency.Field<Int32>("Level")  
 select agency;
```

That will generate [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) operator. Also you can simplify first condition by using [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) method of nullable type:

```
 orderby agency.Field<int?>("ID").GetValueOrDefault(),
         agency.Field<int>("Level")
```

Comment: I think you can also use `agency.Field<Int32?>("ID") ?? 0`.

Comment: Hey busyberezovsky, what about the grouping? ("I would like to group the data by agency - then order").

Comment: @GertArnold hey, I think rows will be 'grouped' by ID (because of sorting by ID first). Thus OP wants result of rows collection type, we can group rows, and then do SelectMany, but that will produce exactly same results as sorting by ID

Comment: Yo, maybe. I'd read it as `groupby`. Anyways, it's the OP's call.